# calling another jquery/AJAX/php request based on the result of the first one is failing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a contact us form with captcha .I submit button click I need to perform a serverside captcha validation using a first AJAX request if success then I call the second AJAX/Jquery/php to send contact us mail .

but the first AJAX call is success ,but second one is not calling .. kindly help me on this ..

```
<form
id="RegisterUserForm"
name="RegisterUserForm"
action=""
onsubmit="return submitform();"
method="post">
    <fieldset
    style="border: 0;">
        <table
        width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td
                width="150">
                    <div
                    class="celebrationContent">
                        Name:</div>
                        </td>
                        <td
                        class="style1">
                            <input
                            id="Name"
                            type="text"
                            name="Name"
                            style="border-style: none; background-color: #fffcc4;
                        width: 275px;"
                            />
                            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div
                    class="celebrationContent">
                        E-mail
                        id:</div>
                </td>
                <td
                class="style1">
                    <input
                    id="email"
                    type="text"
                    name="email"
                    style="border-style: none; background-color: #fffcc4;
                        width: 274px;"
                    />
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td
                class="celebrationContent">
                    Phone
                    Number:
                    </td>
                    <td
                    class="style1">
                        <input
                        id="phonenumber"
                        type="text"
                        name="phonenumber"
                        style="border-style: none;
                        background-color: #fffcc4; width: 274px;"
                        />
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td
                class="celebrationContent">
                    Your
                    Celebration:
                    </td>
                    <td
                    class="style1">
                        <input
                        id="yourCelebration"
                        type="text"
                        name="yourCelebration"
                        style="border-style: none;
                        background-color: #fffcc4; width: 274px; height: auto;"
                        />
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td
                class="celebrationContent">
                    When
                    is
                    it:
                    </td>
                    <td
                    class="style1">
                        <input
                        type="text"
                        name="datepicker"
                        id="datepicker"
                        style="border-style: none; background-color: #fffcc4;
                        width: 272px;"
                        />
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td
                class="celebrationContent">
                    Enquiry:
                    </td>
                    <td
                    class="style1">
                        <input
                        type="text"
                        id="Enquiry"
                        name="Enquiry"
                        style="border-style: none; background-color: #fffcc4;
                        width: 272px; height: 70px;"
                        />
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td
                colspan="2"
                align="left"
                class="celebrationContent">
                    Verification
                    Code
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td
                align="left"
                colspan="2">
                    <table
                    width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td
                            width="32%">
                                <img
                                src="captcha.php"
                                alt="celebration captcha"
                                />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="verificationcode"
                                    name="verificationcode"
                                    style="border-style: none;
                                    background-color: #fffcc4"
                                    />
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td
                colspan="2"
                align="center">
                    <input
                    type="submit"
                    id="form_submit"
                    />
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd-mm-yy');            
        });

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0
        });

    function submitform() {

        if (validateCaptach()) {
            var sData = $("#RegisterUserForm").serialize();
             alert('i am here to process..');  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "thankyou.php",
                data: sData,
                //async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "YESSUCCESS") {
                        alert("Your Query has been sent..");
                       return true;
                    } else {
                        alert("some error please type again...");
                        return false; 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    function validateCaptach() {
        if (validateForm()) {
            var captchaval = $("#verificationcode").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "captchacheck.php",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    verificationcode: captchaval
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                        alert("captchacheck success..");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        alert("The security code you typed was wrong. Please try again.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function validateForm() {

        if (document.RegisterUserForm.Name.value == "") {
            alert("Please provide your name!");
            document.RegisterUserForm.Name.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (document.RegisterUserForm.email.value == "") {
            var emailID = document.RegisterUserForm.email.value;
            atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
            dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos < 1 || (dotpos - atpos < 2)) {
                alert("Please enter correct email ID")
                document.RegisterUserForm.email.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if ((document.RegisterUserForm.phonenumber.value == "") || isNaN(document.RegisterUserForm.phonenumber.value)) {
            alert("Please enter your phone Number");
            document.RegisterUserForm.phonenumber.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.RegisterUserForm.yourCelebration.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your Celebration!");
            document.RegisterUserForm.yourCelebration.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.RegisterUserForm.datepicker.value == "") {
            alert("Please select date !");
            document.RegisterUserForm.datepicker.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.RegisterUserForm.Enquiry.value == "") {
            alert("Please Enter your enquiry!");
            document.RegisterUserForm.Enquiry.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (document.RegisterUserForm.verificationcode.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter the Verificationcode!");
            document.RegisterUserForm.verificationcode.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return (true);
    }    

    </script>
```

Comment: `validateCaptach()` doesn't have a `return` statement. Returning from the `success` function doesn't return from `validateCaptach`.

Comment: I tried that way also .. we need to assign a variable where in return value will be assigned and returned..is it correct please.

Comment: Isn't that what I showed in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `validateCaptach()`. You return `true` or `false` from the AJAX callback function, but those values don't go anywhere.

```
function validateCaptach() {
    if (validateForm()) {
        var captchaval = $("#verificationcode").val();
        var success;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "captchacheck.php",
            async: false,
            data: {
                verificationcode: captchaval
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                    alert("captchacheck success..");
                    success = true;
                } else {
                    alert("The security code you typed was wrong. Please try again.");
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        });
        return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes Barmar , I just updated the code with that ..even then its showing the only alert "captchacheck success" message only .. please

Comment: I'm not sure why. Sorry, but I don't have much experience using synchronous `.ajax()`, maybe it doesn't work the way I thought. You're probably better off using one of the answers that chains callbacks instead of trying to return values synchronously.

Comment: thanks a lot its working . ohhh my GOD you saved my time . Thanks Roberts.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a value from your `validateCaptach`. The return values from `success` event will not be returned to the calling function the way you have handled the code.  So in order for you to get the desired output. You have to make the second call from with in the `success` event of your `ajax` call.

for example

```
  .....
  success: function(e) {
      callSecondFunction();
  }
```

This would be the best approach.

Comment: He has `async: false`, so it's not asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you are using two AJAX requests for this. This doesn't make sence.

You can verify everything in a single AJAX call. Please do captcha check and form submit  in 
`captchacheck.php`

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with asynchronous calls, the function `validateCaptcha` finishes before the ajax call is done. You need to send the second ajax call after the first ajax call has returned sucessfully.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd-mm-yy');            
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});

function submitform () {
    /**
     * Pass the second ajax call as a function
     */
    validateCaptcha(function(){
        var sData = $("#RegisterUserForm").serialize();
        alert('i am here to process..');  

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "thankyou.php",
            data: sData,
            //async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "YESSUCCESS") {
                    alert("Your Query has been sent..");
                   return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("some error please type again...");
                    return false; 
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return false;
}

function validateCaptcha (action) {
    if (validateForm()) {
        var captchaval = $("#verificationcode").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "captchacheck.php",
            async: false,
            data: {
                verificationcode: captchaval
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                    alert("captchacheck success..");

                    if (typeof action == "function") {
                        action();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("The security code you typed was wrong. Please try again.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

function validateForm () {
    if ($("#RegisterUserForm [name=Name]").val() == "") {
        alert("Please provide your name!");
        $("#RegisterUserForm [name=Name]").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if ($("#RegisterUserForm [name=email]").val() == "") {
        var emailID = $("#RegisterUserForm [name=email]").val();
        atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
        dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");

        if (atpos < 1 || (dotpos - atpos < 2)) {
            alert("Please enter correct email ID")
            $("#RegisterUserForm [name=email]").focus();

            return false;
        }
    }

    if (($("#RegisterUserForm [name=phonenumber]").val() == "") || isNaN($("#RegisterUserForm [name=phonenumber]").val())) {
        alert("Please enter your phone Number");
        $("#RegisterUserForm [name=phonenumber]").focus();

        return false;
    }

    if ($("#RegisterUserForm [name=yourCelebration]").val() == "") {
        alert("Please enter your Celebration!");
        $("#RegisterUserForm [name=yourCelebration]").focus();

        return false;
    }

    if ($("#RegisterUserForm [name=datepicker]").val() == "") {
        alert("Please select date !");
        $("#RegisterUserForm [name=datepicker]").focus();

        return false;
    }

    if ($("#RegisterUserForm [name=Enquiry]").val() == "") {
        alert("Please Enter your enquiry!");
        $("#RegisterUserForm [name=Enquiry]").focus();

        return false;
    }

    if ($("#RegisterUserForm [name=verificationcode]").val() == "") {
        alert("Please enter the Verificationcode!");
        $("#RegisterUserForm [name=verificationcode]").focus();

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
```